# iOS Swift Present View Controller from Filtered List

Tags: ios, swift

I am having a strange problem. Consider the following code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let view = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("weaponDetail") as! WeaponDetailsViewController
    var name = ""
    if resultSearchController.active {
        name = filteredweapons[indexPath.row].name
    } else {
        name = weaponsList[indexPath.row].name
    }
    view.weaponName = name
    view.selectionOnly = selectionOnly
    view.delegate = self
    view.characterID = characterID
    presentViewController(view, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

It's a UITableView with a search bar.  When the list is filtered and an item is tapped I get this error:
Warning: Attempt to present   on  which is already presenting (null)

If the list is unfiltered, it works fine.  What am I missing?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Is the ViewController already presenting another ViewController (like the resultSearchController)? Or do you use a custom Transition?

Comment: Didn't think about the resultSearchController being a ViewController.  So doing resultSearchController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true,completion: nil) did the trick. Thanks!